# Mobile Safari HTML5 video - event listener 'ended' does not fire the 2nd time

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, html5-video

I am trying to add a button when pressed will play a video, and when the video ends an image is displayed. The problem is that the 2nd time i press the button, the video ends, and nothing happens as if the event listener does not get called.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

function playVideo() {
    video.style.display="block";
    //video.load() [adding this the 2nd time wont play]
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false);
}

function videoEnd() {
    video.style.display="none";
    bg_image.src="image.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I have found that adding video.currentTime=0.1; to videoEnd() will let the event listener fire a 2nd time, but the 3rd time, it doesnt work.

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact problem, but on desktop Safari (5.0.5).

Comment: Did you try adding video.stop() before your load() or play() call?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a strange bug in Safari's HTML5 video tag implementation. It can be reproduced on Safari for Windows as well. I've just found one workaround for this problem - just bind to `loadedmetadata` event and set the `currentTime` to some non-zero value. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
var src = [
 "http://content.adfox.ru/131007/adfox/205544/865991_11.mp4",
 "http://all.rutube.ru/130627/gpmdigital/217059/805529_11.mp4"
];
var curSrc = 0;
$(function() {
 $('#video').attr("src", src[curSrc % src.length]);
 curSrc++;
 var video = $('#video').get(0);

 $('#video')
 .on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  video.currentTime=0.01;
  video.play();
 })
 .on('ended', function() {
  console.log('ended');
  video.src = src[curSrc % src.length];
  video.load();
  curSrc++;
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try this demo in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2knz6sv/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "ended" event no longer fires when a VIDEO element reaches the end. Apparently only the "pause" event fires.

I've gotten around this by simply listening to the "timeupdate" event and associating a handler method that checks if the currentTime property is equivalent to the duration property of the VIDEO element.

**UPDATE:** I sometimes see the "ended" event in iOS. I always see the "pause" event. Here's some jQuery code that displays this information in the browser console:

```
    (function ($) {
        $("#vid").bind("timeupdate", function (e) {
            console.log(e.type + " - " + (this.currentTime == this.duration));
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: here one writes that ended does not show because video stops before duration total time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714385/html-5-video-ended

Answer (score -3):

You should use timeupdate like this:

```
this.currentTime >= (this.duration-1)
```

Otherwise, it doesn't fire an event.