# HTML5 Video not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'm creating a website for a client that is very media heavy, so has a lot of video/audio files to load. The videos load perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, IE etc, but not Safari (on Windows)! See code below.

```
<video controls="controls" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/malagnini/video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/malagnini/video/sample.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="/malagnini/video/sample.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

All MIME types are added to htaccess file already.

I'm using AJAX to load in some of the videos (e.g when a user clicks on a 'video-type' filter button), so I am loading the videos after each request, which I know Safari has issues with. But even before the request, videos are not playing.

Are there any other boxes I need to tick? (I have QuickTime installed, which I know is required to run HTML5 video via Safari on Windows).

By the way, the video's DO load in iPhone, but they take a very long time to load.

Comment: Safari on Windows has been pretty much end of life'd - even with QT installed I've never had a particularly good experience. Do you have any idea what %age of your users have that combinations

Comment: No, I don't have figures. But I have solved this now - it was a Safari bug whereby new videos are not loaded when the src is dynamically changed. Answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is now solved. Safari has a bug whereby videos whose src attributes are modified dynamically cannot be loaded.

To resolve this, the video element must be cloned then deleted. The src path can be updated to the cloned element, reloaded into the DOM and then loaded as normal.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Safari. Could you give an example of the fix?

Answer (score 0):

@FunnyOxymoron Clonning & deleting `<video>` elements is not a good idea, because on iPhone/iPads user will have to click play button again in order to activate `<video>` object. The right solution is to replace the `src` attribute - and by the way it works on Safari as well. See the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284512/2079326